# I am having problems making two independent oscillators with a CD40106

Tags: oscillator

I'm having problems making two different oscillators with one CD40106 chip. For the first one, I'm using the first hex inverter to make a sawtooth oscillator with the pin 1 and 2.  When I make the second one (which is a square oscillator) with pins 13 and 12, the variations from this one have influence on the sawtooth oscillator, changing the pitch.  I want that the first and the second oscillator sound totally independent without influence from the other.

Here's the schematic:

[image]

I don't know what is happening here.

I'm using a decoupling capacitor of 1uF on the Vcc input and a 9V battery as a power supply. The idea of the circuit is to make a synth oscillators.

[image]

Comment: Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: PCB or solderless breadboard? Are you using decoupling caps close to the IC? Can you post a picture?

Comment: It's on a solderless breadboard.

Comment: Circuits sharing an IC in close proximity will often interact. They are sharing ground and Vcc wires and there may be electrostatic and magnetic coupling. Is the difference barely detectable to your ear, or a huge change? A human can detect about a 0.3% change in frequency.

Comment: Huge change. It feels like a vibrato effect.

Comment: Using higher impedances will help for a start. Notice the zener diode gives a very low resistance path from one output to the capacitor, charging it in a relative hurry (the output resistance is in the 200-400 ohm range at 9V, I believe?), at least in one direction. And the other with 1k is barely more than the gate's output impedance. Both currents make a big difference across internal resistances on the chip, and through the shared power pin (which is bypassed by a small capacitor in comparison to those in circuit). The 9V itself doesn't have low resistance either.

Comment: In short, try larger impedances, like 100kΩ and 1uF, and maybe use a transistor to discharge C2 instead of charging it through the gate. (Also, is that actually a zener?)

Comment: Vibrato may only be a few percent and may seem huge to a musician, but not an engineer. Do you have any way to quantitatively measure the frequency change? A scope would give you a rough measurement.

Comment: The contact resistance of a solderless breadboard can be 1 ohm or more, so minimizing current should help (as Tim suggests).

Comment: @Zlmanuel87, problem could also be the high current through LED1 when it is ON. There is no current limiting resistor. That may cause supply to dip and affect the other circuit. Add a 2.7k resistor in series with LED1 and see if it helps solve the issue.

Comment: @sai - Yes!, You should write that as an answer. The rest of us missed it.

Comment: @sai The breadboard appears to have one. The schematic isn't quite in sync I think. Always hard to tell, though.

Comment: @TimWilliams, indeed, the schematic seems incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the problem is not adding current limiting resistor in series with the LED1. This would cause a dip on supply and affect the sawtooth generator. Adding a resistor in series with LED1 should fix the issue of square wave oscillator affecting the sawtooth generator.

Edit: Make sure that the current output drawn is within the limits mentioned in the datasheet

Answer (score 4):

Both oscillator circuits have issues.

The CD40106 is rated to source or sink 2.5 mA when operating on 10 V (the closest condition in the datasheet to your 9 V supply).  In the left circuit, this current has to both charge/discharge a relatively large timing capacitor *plus* light the LED.  You are way overextending the chip's capabilities.  When the output changes state, there is over 4 V across R1.  Even without considering the LED, you are trying to draw 4 mA from a source rated for 2.5 mA.

To fix this, decrease C1 to 1 uF and increase R1 to 100K.  This will reduce the demand on the inverter output stage to something it can handle with ease.  Next, do not try to drive the oscillator feedback and the LED from the same pin.  Even with an added current-limiting resistor, the LED current will subtract from the feedback current in one-half of the waveform but not the other.  This will make the output square wave noticeably less symmetrical.  Use another inverter section to drive the LED, isolating the LED current from the current needed by C1.  Connect the oscillator output pin directly to the input of another inverter, and (as in other posts) add a current limiting resistor in series with the LED.  Again, keep the LED current at or below 2.5 mA

The right circuit has a couple of problems.  Because there is no current-limiting element in the series feedback element (D1), this circuit has the same output overcurrent problems as the left circuit.  Also, the voltage waveform across C2 will be very asymmetrical, but it will not approximate a true sawtooth waveform.

To get a better approximation of a sawtooth across C2, replace D1 with a small signal diode such as a 1N914 or 1N4148, and place a timing resistor (R7) in parallel with it.  With the new D1 oriented as shown, the C2 voltage waveform will have a relatively fast risetime (set by the value of C2 and the output impedance of the inverter) and a much slower fall time set by C2 and the added R7.  If you want a fast fall and slow rise, reverse the diode.

This will briefly overload the output stage during the rapid part of the cycle.  To protect the inverter output, add another resistor (R8), this time between the inverter output and the diode-resistor feedback elements.  This solves one problem, but might create another.  The closer R7 and R8 are in value, the more the C2 voltage will approximate a triangle wave instead of a saw wave.  For a much better saw approximation, the two resistors should be at least 10x apart.  100x is better.  I can't be more specific that that because . . .

NOTE:  Nowhere in your post do you say what frequencies you want for the two oscillators.  This makes it very difficult to give a better answer.

The function of R4 and R6 are not clear.  Adjusting R4 will change the oscillator frequency, the sawtooth amplitude, and the sawtooth shape.  What are you trying to achieve here?  Whatever it is, there is a better way.

Good use of reference designators.  Pleas add pin numbers to the inverters.

Comment: ¡Thank you! It works.